# Skip multiple loop iterations

Tags: r, for-loop, skip

I am trying to program a script that skips the next two iterations if it finds a data-match.
For one iteration I could use the "next" command, but that doesn't work for skipping several iterations.

Here's my script.

```
rowsToDelete<-c()

for(o in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$reactionTime[o]>2000||data$V8[o]<9999){

      rowsToDelete<-rbind(rowsToDelete,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
      o<-o+2

  }
  else{
      rowsToDelete<-rbind(rowsToDelete,FALSE)
  }
}
```

I just cant figure out why the part with `o<-o+2` in the if loop does not skip the next two iterations, it just enlarges the amount of iterations from 13000 to 14430 (The difference is the amount of bad cases in my data times 2).

Comment: could you describe exactly what you are trying to do? there may be a simpler way to do it. (for example, get which rows fulfill the conditions and then deduce which rows you need to delete). (nb: as `rowsToDelete` is a vector, use `c(rowsToDelete, ...)` instead of `rbind`)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to manage the counter yourself with `repeat` and `break` like this:

```
rowsToDelete<-c()
o<-1
 repeat{
  if(data$reactionTime[o]>2000||data$V8[o]<9999){
    rowsToDelete<-rbind(rowsToDelete,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
    o<-o+2  
  }
  else{
    rowsToDelete<-rbind(rowsToDelete,FALSE)
    o<-o+1
  }

  if (o == nrow(data)) break
}
```

Comment: I would suggest literally *any* other solution. This is how you’d program in C, not in R.

Answer (score 1):

R operates differently, in two regards.

1. `for` loops do not work like this — you cannot modify the loop variable, as you’ve noticed yourself. Furthermore, you’re normally not iterating over indices, but rather over elements directly.
2. To select or remove specific objects from a vector/matrix/data.frame, you just select those elements via a numeric or logical index. Your code is already going in this direction, but you’re constructing this index (`rowsToDelete`) iteratively rather than in one go

As a corollary of (2), don’t create vectors or lists in a row by iterative concatenation — it’s really, really slow.

Here’s a different way, using R’s vectorised expressions:

```
rowsToDelete = data$reactionTime > 2000 | data$V8 < 9999
```

Note that I’ve replaced `||` with the vectorised `|`. This returns a vector whose elements are `TRUE` where the condition is met. Next, we need to extend this logical vector such that, if an element at index *i* is `TRUE`, those at indices *i*+1 and *i*+2 will also be `TRUE`:

```
rowsToDelete = rowsToDelete | c(FALSE, rowsToDelete) | c(FALSE, FALSE, rowsToDelete)
```

This simply shifts the vector by one element, and then by two elements, and combines them via logical “or”. However, note that this results in warnings, since now the vectors we’re combining via “or” no longer have the same length. In general, it’s a good idea to heed this warning. We can avoid it here with the use of a little helper function:

```
shift = function (x, element = FALSE) c(element, x[-length(x)])

rowsToDelete = data$reactionTime > 2000 | data$V8 < 9999
rowsToDelete = rowsToDelete | shift(rowsToDelete) | shift(shift(rowsToDelete))
```